# What is the .NET equivalent of java's -verbose:gc command line option

Tags: c#, java, .net, performance, garbage-collection

I'm writting an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm seeing a seemly random performance from a one of my actions. My initial throught is that the garbage collection is kicking in and pausing the app for a little while, but I can't seem to find a button/switch that will prove or disprove my theory.

For none java people out there `-verbose:gc` is a command line switch that you can pass to a java application that will make the JVM print out when a GC event happens and how long it takes.

I've attempted to use the vs2010 performance tool and JetBrains dotTrace both of which are a little bit like using a thermo nuclear weapon to crack a small nut.

Comment: how long the GC takes isn't that easily defined. Most of the GC doesn't require a stopped program, since .net uses a concurrent GC on client applications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In .NET 4.0 there is Event tracing for Windows (ETW) that provides you with the information you are looking for. Here is a one specific for [GC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356162.aspx).

FYI ETW is very fast and built into Kernel. With ETW you should be able to get information like this
[image]

[image]

And to get this information there is a tool from the BCL team which is called [PerfMonitor](http://bcl.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PerfMonitor&referringTitle=Home)

Here are the steps in using the tool to get the GC Information

1. Start a cmd or powershell  as admin
   , this required to collect ETW
   tracing
2. Start the application that you want
   to trace
3. Issue the command “PerfMonitor.exe
   /process:4180 start” where 4180 is
   the process id
4. Do the necessary actions
5. Then issue “PerfMonitor.exe stop”
6. The command to get the report
   “PerfMonitor.exe GCTime”. This will
   generate a report and open it in the
   browser

I have also [blogged](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/08/10/get-gc-information-in-silverlight/) the about the same

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your first guess should not be the GC. With all normal workloads you don't notice the GC in .NET.

There is no trace-switch for the GC, but you can look at the [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx#S2) if you still think the GC is to blame.

Comment: Thanks that does just the job. Your quite right it's nothing todo with GC, couldn't be easy :-)